# Code for textfield character limit isn't working(SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

I've stumbled across this piece of code:

```
class TextLimiter: ObservableObject {
private let limit: Int

init(limit: Int) {
    self.limit = limit
}

@Published var value = "" {
    didSet {
        if value.count > self.limit {
            value = String(value.prefix(self.limit))
            self.hasReachedLimit = true
        } else {
            self.hasReachedLimit = false
        }
    }
}

@Published var hasReachedLimit = false }

struct Strix: View {
@ObservedObject var input = TextLimiter(limit: 5)
var body: some View {
    TextField("Text Input",
        text: $input.value)
            .border(Color.red,
                   width: $input.hasReachedLimit.wrappedValue ? 1 : 0 )
   } }
```

It's a TextField limiting code where after a user inputs characters after a limit, it won't keep inputing characters inside the box. I've tried this code and after the limit is reached, it just keeps on inputting characters.

For example:

> How it's supposed to work: limit is 5 so the only input allowed is 'aaaaa'

> How it's behaving: limit is 5 but input allowed is  'aaaaaaaa.....'

I'm aware of a recent solution to this:

> [How to set textfield character limit SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223276/how-to-set-textfield-character-limit-swiftui)

but the solution is specifically tailored for iOS 14. I was hoping to be able to support iOS 13. Thanks.

Link to original code:

> https://github.com/programmingwithswift/SwiftUITextFieldLimit/blob/master/SwiftUITextFieldLimit/SwiftUITextFieldLimit/ContentView.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is lies in SwiftUI's subscriber `.onReceive`,

Make sure that your property `hasReachedLimit` must not marked with `@Published` else it will trigger infinite loop of view body rendering.

Below shown code works as your expectation.

```
class TextLimiter: ObservableObject {
    let limit: Int
    @Published var value = ""
    var hasReachedLimit = false
        
    init(limit: Int) {
        self.limit = limit
    }
}

struct Strix: View {
    @ObservedObject var input = TextLimiter(limit: 5)
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text Input",
                  text: $input.value)
            .border(Color.red,
                    width: $input.hasReachedLimit.wrappedValue ? 1 : 0 )
            .onReceive(Just(self.input.value)) { inputValue in
                
                self.input.hasReachedLimit = inputValue.count > self.input.limit
                
                if inputValue.count > self.input.limit {
                    self.input.value.removeLast()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

BTW this is not an efficient solution.